# Visual C++ debugger visualizer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, debuggervisualizer

How does Visual Studio show the elements of a vector, or the characters of a string, in C++? Is there a way for me to make it show my own classes in a custom way?

Comment: Also see [Boost 1.54 multiprecision visualizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/misc/visualizers.html). It adds entries to `autoexp.dat`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf0e8s14(v=VS.100).aspx

> For native code, you can add custom data type expansions to the file
>   autoexp.dat, which is located in the Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger directory. Instructions on how
>   to write autoexp rules are located in the file itself.

For this class:

```
template<class T>
struct  auto_array {
     T* data;
     int Len;
};
```

the autoexp.data might look like:

```
auto_array<*> {
    children
    (
        #array
        (
            expr :      $e.Data[$i],
            size :      $e.Len
        )
    )
    preview
    (
        #(
            "[", $e.Len , "](",
            #array
            (
                expr :  $e.Data[$i],
                size :  $e.Len
            ),
            ")"
        )
    )
}
```

[KindDragon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61505/kinddragon) reports that Visual Studio 2012 uses a new file format: [natvis](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/07/12/10329460.aspx)

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 uses a new file format natvis http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/07/12/10329460.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can add visualizers for custom C++ types to the autoexp.dat file. The format used in the file and the location change from version to version of Visual Studio but if you Google for autoexp.dat you should find some examples of how to customize it.

Answer (score 2):

For VS2017/2015, use [Natvis visualizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects) to Create custom views of native objects in the Visual Studio debugger.