# Customizing the VS C++ debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual C++ debugger visualizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420842/visual-c-debugger-visualizer)

Are there any good tutorials on customizing the Visual Studio C++ 2010 debugger, so that I can change the way that some data structures are visualized ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the links in [Visual C++ debugger visualizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420842/visual-c-debugger-visualizer)

http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=120

http://filetolink.com/17ad36ef

also go to http://channel9.msdn.com and search for visualizers