# Custom container browsable in debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Arrays and std::vectors (and, supposedly, all standard containers) are browseable in the Visual Studio debugger (you can hover the mouse pointer over them and inspect their contents).

Is there a way to prepare a custom container class, to allow browsing through its internal data the same way as std::vector does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to look at file `%VSINSTALLDIR%\Common7\Packages\Debugger\autoexp.dat`.
There is customizable description of expansion rules for different data types.

From this file:

> While debugging, Data Tips and items in the Watch and Variable windows
>   are automatically expanded to show their most important elements. The
>   expansion follows the format given by the rules in this file. You can
>   add rules for your types or change the predefined rules.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420842/visual-c-debugger-visualizer)

Answer (score 2):

With modern version of visual studio you can create a .natvis file describing how to read the data structure.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2022

For example, a custom vector type class:

````xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
  <Type Name="vec&lt;*,*&gt;">
    <DisplayString Condition="m_size == 0">empty</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString>{&amp;m_data[0], [m_size]}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="[size]">m_size,d</Item>
      <Item Name="[capacity]">m_capacity,d</Item>
      <ArrayItems>
        <Size>m_size</Size>
        <ValuePointer>&amp;m_data[0]</ValuePointer>
      </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>```
````

Comment: I've tried that, but doesn't work